# Should an xsd have only one schema definition?

Tags: xsd

Im trying to create a xsd from a wsdl file.
The wsdl file has 3 schemas defined with 1 of them being a parent and having dependencies on the other two.

Wanted to know if I can have these 3 schemas defined in a single xsd or I need to have 3 seperate xsds.

Answer (score 0):

If those schemas have different namespaces, then they need to be 3 separate xsd.